# Add leading zeroes to have every filename same length

Tags: batch-file

As the title says I want every filename in C:\plantje to have the same length of 9 characters. All the files are .txt files. Their names are only numbers. So if I have a file of 3 characters I want six 0's in front of it. And when it's a file of 6 characters I want three 0's in front of it. I know other people asked the same question but after 8 hours of trying it doesn't work for me. (I'm a beginner at batch files.)

The best script I have is this

```
@echo off

for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do ren "%%f" "0%%f"

pause
```

But this standard adds one 0 in front of the files.
It would be very great if someone could help me out! (I don't think it's very difficult, but I just can't fix it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general methodology is to add zeroes to the beginning of the name, then select the last nine characters using delayed substring expansion.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A-D "*.txt" 2^>NUL') Do (
    Set "BaseName=00000000%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo=Ren "%%G" "!BaseName:~-9!%%~xG"
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```

*`Echo=` is added to the above for demonstration purposes. Please remove it if you're satisfied with the returned results.*

Comment: Hello Compo, thank your for your ansver. If im running the script actually nothing happens to the filenames. Do you know why?

Comment: @Stan, are you running the script with `C:\plantje` as the current directory, in the same way as you must have been testing your own? Have your read my answer, in its entirety?

Comment: Yes, i edeleted my own script and pasted yours in it. I also gave it a try local on my computer and it also didnt work..

Comment: Try it now @Stan, there was a typo, I had somehow failed to notice a missing space character on line 3, _(`Delims="%%G` should have been `Delims=" %%G`)_.

Comment: My hero.. I have been looking for this for 2 hours. Now if only I can figure out how to make this work in a sub-directory